# Reactjs not working in firefox and chromium browser

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

My project is running in all browser in development mode.
But in production after running **"npm run build"** it is failing in some browser(like older version of **chrome** browser and **firefox**).

When I am running the build verion in updated chrome browser it is runnning fine but when I am running same build 
in **firefox** or old chrome browser it is showing some **errors**.

like

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'charAt' of null
TypeError: Cannot read property 'componentDidMount' of null
```

But in latest chrome browser it is not showing any error. it is showing fine

This is my package.json file

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@amcharts/amcharts4": "^4.7.8",
    "@amcharts/amcharts4-geodata": "^4.1.8",
    "@syncfusion/ej2-react-dropdowns": "^17.3.28",
    "history": "^4.10.1",
    "html2canvas": "^1.0.0-rc.5",
    "interweave": "^12.1.0",
    "jspdf": "^1.5.3",
    "node-sass": "^4.13.0",
    "postcss-svgo": "^4.0.2",
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-csv": "^1.1.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "react-scripts": "3.3.0",
    "react-select": "^3.0.8",
    "react-toasts": "^3.0.6",
    "reactjs-popup": "^1.5.0",
    "vis": "^4.21.0-EOL"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Would you please add more details about errors you have? It is hard to know which package is not compatible with the other browsers. Where and why did you get `null`?

Comment: Sounds like maybe some JS isn't loading properly, so perhaps it's an issue with your browser and your development server. Check for errors in your network tab.

Answer (score -1):

Try changing the "browserslist" object in package.json.
here is the link to it [Configuring your supported browser](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/supported-browsers-features/#configuring-supported-browsers)

Comment: It is same in my pakage.json like you shared the link